# How to find a flops of a CPU?

Tags: cpu

I'm using Intel Xeon CPU x5660, 2.80GHz 2.79Ghz in a computer.

I'm trying to find the FLOPS of the CPU, have searched on Internet but didn't find anything about it. Does anybody know how can I find it?

Comment: "FLOPS" is no longer a sensible benchmark (hasn't been in over a decade, TBH). The main problem is that there's no clear definition on what one operation is. For instance, is `y=a*x+b` one operation or two? With FMA (Fused Multiply and Add), it's only one, but often it's still counted as two.

Comment: I know that this post is more recent, but there seem to be some good points about flops here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329174/what-is-flop-s-and-is-it-a-good-measure-of-performance

Answer (score 5):

Use [LinX](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Benchmarks/LinX-benchmark.shtml) to find the Giga-FLops your computer can do.

Answer (score -1):

Intel EM64T Xeon X56xx (Westmere-EP) 2930 MHz (11.72 GFlops)
http://top500.org/system/details/10603

Mandelbrot 
multi-core scalar    15.3 Gflops
Dot Product 
multi-core scalar    10.8 Gflops
Dot Product 
multi-core vector    25.1 Gflops
LU Decomposition 
multi-core scalar    6.36 Gflops
Primality Test multi-core scalar           8.15 Gflops

http://browse.geekbench.ca/geekbench2/view/300144